# PHP mail function not sending emails

Tags: php

With this code:

```
    <?php
    $from = "Name <robot@mail.com>";
    $replyto = "mail@domain.com";       
    $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $replyto . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: mail@domain.com'; 

    // Mail it
    
    $message = chunk_split($message, 998);

    echo $headers;
    
    $to = "mail@gmail.com";
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Basically, no emails are sent and no errors are generated.

Can anyone help?

Comment: To see errors you need to [check for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). You don't even check the result of `mail()` itself. However, it is very possible that the mail was sent, but was simply rejected by GMail because you don't own the domain `mail.com` and you didn't use [a properly configured email server](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?sjid=16834620832930418375-EU).

Comment: Also check through https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/231316 which dives deep into email problems

Comment: Thanks for the support. I've tested sending to a Gmail account and to another. It doesn't send to email. I've also searched the errors (no error), and asked my host to configure the mail server, although everyting is just too complicated

Comment: `mail()` does not actually send mail, it just passes the mail to the mail server configured in your `php.ini`. If hosted then you could expect that to have been done correctly. However, all hosted servers now tend to insist that the FROM address actually exits as a valid email address on your server. SO, does `robot@mail.com` actually exist on your hosted system?

Comment: That's interesting. Yes, the email account actually exists and it is configured to send emails but not to receive incoming emails.